# parse that CSV at launch via a VB script

Tags: vbscript

We have a dump of the vCenter to VM mappings to a CSV somewhere globally accessible (UNC share), and have BGinfo parse that CSV at launch via a VB script.

Comment: Get `strComputer = CreateObject("Wscript.Network").ComputerName` and inside the `while` loop e.g. `If UCase(Replace(arrStr(0),"""","")) = UCase(strComputer) Then wscript.echo strComputer & " (VCenter) :" & arrStr(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign IP address to variable named `VCenter` if server name match (otherwise, assign a zero-length string):

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0

'You should use a SPLIT command !
Dim fso,objTextFile, strComputer
' get local computer name 
strComputer = CreateObject("Wscript.Network").ComputerName
 
set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
dim arrStr, filepath
filepath = "C:\BgInfo\vmdumps.csv"  
set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath)

Dim VCenter   ''' assign a variable this value
VCenter = ""
Do while NOT objTextFile.AtEndOfstream 
   arrStr = split(objTextFile.ReadLine,",")
   If UCase(Replace(arrStr(0),"""","")) = UCase(strComputer) Then 
      ' wscript.echo strComputer & " (VCenter) :" & arrStr(1)
      VCenter = Replace(arrStr(1),"""","")
   Else
      ' wscript.echo arrStr(0) & " : " & arrStr(1)
   End If 
Loop
objTextFile.Close 
If Not VCenter = "" Then
  ''' do something, e.g. demonstrate correct assignment
  wscript.echo strComputer & ": VCenter found at " & VCenter
Else
  ''' do something else e.g. show that the variable is and empty string
  wscript.echo strComputer & ": VCenter not found" & VCenter
End If
```

**Output** on different servers with the same file contents:

Example *VCenter **not found***: `cscript D:\bat\SO\67533523.vbs`

```
My-Server: VCenter found at 10.10.10.10
```

Example *VCenter **found***: `cscript D:\bat\SO\67533523.vbs`

```
Xx-Server: VCenter not found
```